# Trapezoid - find length and area

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me on this problem? The following problem has a solution, but I can't understand it. In the solution, it draws a dash line CF in parallel with AD and says that ∠BCF=∠FCD=∠BFC. I don't get why the three angles are equal.

Problem: In trapezoid ABCD, AB||DC and BD⊥AD, BC=CD=7, AD=8. Find the length of AB, and the area of ABCD.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $|AB|=:c$, $|BD|=:a$, and $\angle(ABD)=:\alpha$. Then
$$\cos\alpha={a\over c}={a/2\over 7}$$
implies $c=14$. It then follows that $$\left({a\over2}\right)^2={196-64\over4}=33\ ,$$ so that the height of the isosceles triangle $DBC$ comes to $\sqrt{49-33}=4$. The area  of the trapezoid $T=ABCD$ is then given by
$${\rm area}(T)={1\over2}a(8+4)=12\sqrt{33}\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

Because $AD//FC$, so $CF\perp BD$

Then since $\Delta BCD$ is an isosceles triangle, $CF$ would be the angle bisector of $\angle BCD$

Answer (score 0):

The given $ABCD$ trapezoid is as follows:

[image: trapezoid for the question]

Draw a line $CF$ from point $C$ so that it meets $AB$ at $F$ and $DB$ at $G$ while $CF \bot DB$. Since $\angle ADB = \angle DGC = 90^\circ$, $AD \parallel CF$. Therefore, since $AB \parallel DC$, $ADCF$ is a parallelogram. Hence, $CF = AD = 8$ and $AF = DC = 7$.

Consider the $\triangle BCD$. Since $CD = CB = 7$, $\angle CDB = \angle CBD = \alpha$. Consequently, $\angle GCB = \angle GCD = \beta = 90^\circ - \alpha$ and $DG = GB$.

Similarly, since $FB \parallel CD$ of $BCDF$ quadrilateral, $\angle FBD = \angle CDB = \alpha$ and $\angle BFC = \angle DCF = \beta = 90^\circ - \alpha$. Now, consider the triangles, $\triangle BCG$ and $\triangle BFG$. Since $\angle CBG = \angle FBG = \alpha$, $\angle BCG = \angle BFG = \beta = 90^\circ - \alpha$, and the side $BG$ is common for both triangles, $\triangle BCG \equiv \triangle BFG$. Consequently, $BF = BC = 7$ and $FG = CG$. That means, $BCDF$ quadrilateral is a rhombus.

Since $\triangle ABD$ is a right triangle, $BD^2 = AB^2 - AD^2 = 14^2 - 8^2 = 132$.
Therefore, $ BD = \sqrt{132} = 2\sqrt{33}$.

Therefore, $AB = AF + FB = 7 + 7 = 14$. Thus, $DG = GB = \frac12 BD = \sqrt{33}$. Hence $CG = \sqrt{DC^2 - DG^2}= \sqrt{49 - 33} = \sqrt{16} = 4$.

If area of $ABCD$ trapezoid is $A_{ABCD}$:
$$A_{ABCD} = A_{\triangle ABD} + A_{\triangle BCD} = \frac12(AD \cdot DB) + \frac12(BD \cdot CG) = \frac12(8 \cdot 2\sqrt{33}) + \frac12(2\sqrt{33} \cdot 4)\\ = 12\sqrt{33}$$